# Can I use everything from Android SDK?

Tags: android

Can I use everything which is included in Android SDK? I need to use some images, styles, etc. Is it OK if I just copy required resources to my workspace, is it allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dont ask legal question on developers forum. You are bound to get simple, logical and wrong answers.
2. There are [licensing terms](http://developer.android.com/sdk/terms.html). You should read them. If you are doing this for commercial purposes, then a lawyer should read them also.

Comment: "Images, styles, etc." are also in the Android Open Source Project and are licensed under the Apache Software License. Those items in text format (e.g., XML) typically mention this somewhere in the top of the file (e.g., comment block). If you are concerned about whether something that ships with the SDK is only available under the SDK terms and conditions, hunt for the same item in http://source.android.com.

Comment: Yes I know. I often dig into source for answers. But I avoid giving legal advice because IANAL. And I always advise people agains seeking legal advice from anyone but lawyers.

Comment: True enough. Your answer just seemed scarier than is probably required here, though. :-)

Comment: Scary is good. Think about a larger commercial project where one developer uses a crucial library that is under GPL and management had no idea what IP due dilligence is. I've seen it in first person. OP is at least thinking about it, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

As far as icons are meant - you can copy them. It's a suggestion:

> Warning: Because these resources can change between platform versions,
>   you should not reference these icons using the Android platform
>   resource IDs (i.e. menu icons under android.R.drawable). If you want
>   to use any icons or other internal drawable resources, you should
>   store a local copy of those icons or drawables in your application
>   resources, then reference the local copy from your application code.
>   In that way, you can maintain control over the appearance of your
>   icons, even if the system's copy changes. Note that the grid below is
>   not intended to be complete.

I think styles are ok too - but this is my personal opinion.