# Include resources in my app from sdk folder

Tags: android

I want to include some drawables from ***sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\drawable-hdpi*** folder with my app and the entire ***sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\values\dimens.xml*** file.

What should I do ?
I don't know if I must include some Attribution in my **About screen** and if so wich is  the right way.

Comment: All your /res folder is included when you sign and zip the application.

Comment: Yes but I want to use a Holo resource in Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the drawables from `sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\drawable-hdpi` in your project's `drawable-hdpi` folder. Rename these to avoid name conflict.

Alternatively, you can place these drawables in your `assets` folder. I doubt that any of the drawables will be > 1 MB in size (there's a system-imposed size limit). To access them in code:

```
try {
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("some_drawable.png"), 
                                                                                   null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // catch
}
```

For the `sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\values\dimens.xml`, copy required `<dimen name="some_name">some_value</dimen>` and paste them in your `res/values/dimens.xml`. Again, be careful about name conflicts.

Comment: What about Attribution, should I include it somewhere and if so where ?

Comment: `res/values/dimens.xml` is licensed under the Apache license, Vsersion 2.0. You can read through the terms of this license at: [Apache License, Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). You should include the copyright notice in the file that contains the copied values. More on this here: [Can I use a library under the Apache Software License 2.0 in a commercial application? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007338/can-i-use-a-library-under-the-apache-software-license-2-0-in-a-commercial-applic).

Comment: And this is directly related to the question you asked. See `CommonsWare's` comment on `Peter Knego's` answer: [Can I use everything from Android SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222764/can-i-use-everything-from-android-sdk).